# Mathematical applications of level curves?

Tags: vector-analysis

What can level curves be used for?

I've heard of that they can be used to approximate for the maximum (and minimum) of a function, but what else?

Is finding the maximum and minimum always using level curves an approximation? Can one find the exact points?

Also, are level curve applications predominantly done on computers?

Comment: Contour maps, isobars, $\dots$.

Comment: What kind of apllications are you looking for? Real life, general science or mathematical?

Comment: @Evgeny Predominantly mathematical.